# Set and run mysql trigger on sequence.

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 3 triggers in mysql. Is there a way to create sequence on running the triggers like sql server?

Comment: this may be helpful [Triggers and sequences in MySQL](https://docs.chemaxon.com/display/docs/Triggers+and+sequences+-+MySQL) and [simulating sequences in mysql](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/simulating-sequences-in-mysql/)

Comment: Can you give us more details?. `... trigger_order clause that indicates FOLLOWS or PRECEDES and the name of an existing trigger that also has the same trigger event and action time.`, see [13.1.20 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).